# How to remove character from tuples in list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

How to remove "(" ,")" form

```
[('(10', '40)'), ('(40', '30)'), ('(20', '20)')]
```

by python?

Comment: Can you provide more code demonstrating how you reached this point?  The issue is probably in the way your data was generated and could be approached differently to avoid having to solve this "problem".

Comment: I try format string: ((10 40), (40 30), (20 20), (30 10)) to list of tuple.

Comment: @flup you're right, I'm deleting my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you are currently storing the list:

```
def to_int(s):
    s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch.isdigit())
    return int(s)

lst = [('(10', '40)'), ('(40', '30)'), ('(20', '20)')]

lst = [(to_int(a), to_int(b)) for a,b in lst] # => [(10, 40), (40, 30), (20, 20)]
```

or

```
import ast

s = "[('(10', '40)'), ('(40', '30)'), ('(20', '20)')]"
s = s.replace("'(", "'").replace(")'", "'")
lst = ast.literal_eval(s)               # => [('10', '40'), ('40', '30'), ('20', '20')]
lst = [(int(a), int(b)) for a,b in lst] # => [(10, 40), (40, 30), (20, 20)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward, use list comprehension and literal_eval.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> tuple_list = [('(10', '40)'), ('(40', '30)'), ('(20', '20)')]
>>> [literal_eval(','.join(i)) for i in tuple_list]
[(10, 40), (40, 30), (20, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [('(10', '40)'), ('(40', '30)'), ('(20', '20)')]
>>> [tuple((subl[0].lstrip("("), subl[1].rstrip(")"))) for subl in L]
[('10', '40'), ('40', '30'), ('20', '20')]
```

Or if you wan the numbers in your tuples to eventually be `int`s:

```
>>> [tuple((int(subl[0].lstrip("(")), int(subl[1].rstrip(")")))) for subl in L]
[(10, 40), (40, 30), (20, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.strip('()')` on individual items (if they are strings, like in your example) to strip trailing `(` and `)`.

There are multiple ways to apply that on single elements:

**list comprehension (most pythonic)**

```
a = [tuple(x.strip('()') for x in y) for y in a]
```

**`map` and `lambda` (interesting to see)**

Python 3:

```
def cleanup(a: "list<tuple<str>>") -> "list<tuple<int>>":
    return list(map(lambda y: tuple(map(lambda x: x.strip('()'), y)), a))

a = cleanup(a)
```

Python 2:

```
def cleanup(a):
    return map(lambda y: tuple(map(lambda x: x.strip('()'), y)), a)

a = cleanup(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Process the original string instead. Let's call it `a`.

On `a='((10 40), (40 30), (20 20), (30 10))'` , you can call

```
[tuple(x[1:-1].split(' ')) for x in a[1:-1].split(', ')]
```

The `[1:-1]` trims brackets from the string, the `split`s split strings into lists of strings. 
The `for` is a comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "((10 40), (40 30), (20 20), (30 10))"
print [[int(x) for x in inner.strip(' ()').split()] for inner in s.split(',')]

# or if you actually need tuples:
tuple([tuple([int(x) for x in inner.strip(' ()').split()]) for inner in s.split(',')])
```